# Как убрать отступы в textarea (Safari для iPad)?

Tags: css, вёрстка, ipad, safari, textarea

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что у элемента **textarea** не получается полностью убрать отступ в Safari (iPad). Даже при `margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;` текст все равно смещается вправо и вниз на несколько пикселей (то есть его нельзя подогнать впритык к краю textarea).

У элемента input такой проблемы нет. Также текст правильно смещается во всех остальных браузерах, включая десктопную версию Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опытным путем выяснил, что смещение элемента (extra margins) является общим явлением для всех устройств iOS (смещение textarea на 3 пикселя). Единственный вариант - вручную смещать `text-indent`, когда пользователь заходит через iPhone/iPad:

```
if(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  for(i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++){
    textareas[i].style['text-indent'] = '-3px';
  }
}
```